# What does down arrow View called?

Tags: android, view

what does this view 'look like down arrow' called?  i did Search with picture for this `View` but didn't find result .

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) view, and the tutorial on how to use them is given in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html). Spinners are basically drop-down menus where the user may choose one option the programmer defined.